# Looking for a planetary calculator for the mass, density, and/or radius of a planet?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, worldbuilding-resources

I am looking for calculator which can derive the following:

- Diameter
- Density (g/cm3)
- Surface Area
- Roche Limit
- Surface Gravity
- “To Orbit Velocity” (km/sec)
- Thrust to orbit time at 3G
- Escape Velocity (km/sec)
- Geosynchronous orbital distance & velocity
- Any other interesting aspects

Does anyone know of a planetary calculator of this type?

Comment: I think this question would be better as a post on the Meta. I can't see a question about world-building, just about  a list of tools for helping with worldbuilding. And it might be a good idea to link the one you found in the Meta post.

Comment: I took the liberty to improve your question's readability. Can you provide a link to your calculator?

Comment: @Secespitus we have a dedicated tag for world building resources. This is on-topic IMHO.

Comment: @Secespitus Questions seeking software or other resource recommendations are generally on topic if they are about resources useful for worldbuilding purposes and are appropriately scoped. That said, this would be much, *much* better if OP can give clear criteria for "better". Higher precision calculations? (Than what?) Allows more inputs? Gives a different set of outputs? (In both cases, which ones?) **Just "better" is prone to be subjective; please be specific.** I'm voting to put this on hold as primarily opinion-based for the time being, but would be happy to vote to reopen once edited.

Comment: How about a simple spreadsheet?

Comment: Here's the URL: http://www.transhuman.talktalk.net/gt/Geosync.htm.

Comment: About "specifically better" I mean either with more explanation (I'm about as far away from being a physicist as imaginable) e.g., why is "3G": "Thrust to orbit time at 3G" or with any other info pertinent to world building. About whether it belongs in a "meta" or not, every planet in the Solar System (plus Pluto) is listed as well as options for, "Random Main World," "Random Large Moon," "Random Large Gas Giant," and "Random Small Gas Giant."

Comment: This is the second time you've posted this information. The problem this time is you have proposed it as a question of is there a better calculator. The "better" part of the question makes it subjective & your Q has been jumped on because that single word. Try and edit your Q so it asks are there calculators that can calculate the following from these inputs (choose your own form of words).In the body of your Q ask for a calculator to provide planetary data of the sort your want. Then you can answer your own Q and give the link to it. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: @a4android - My apologizes; I'm still figuring out how the mechanics of this site works.

Comment: You don't need to apologize. I was trying to help you know what wasn't working with your question. The mechanics of the WB site isn't easy. It's not intuitive. I hope you don't mind, I will edit your question into what I think is appropriate -- and I might get it wrong too. My edit is indicative and not the last word on anything. OK? If you don't like my edit, you can make your own edit. And that's cool too!

Comment: Your question has been edited and I voted to reopen it. Hang in there, try your hand at answering a few questions, that's always good fun, be patient and you'll learn to navigate the site.

Comment: @a4android - Thank you on both counts.

Comment: artefaxian on youtube has video tutorials on how to calculate all those things.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to "is there a better tool than the one at http://www.transhuman.talktalk.net/gt/Geosync.htm" is no.

That is not to say that it could not be improved upon by taking the output fields and converting them into fields that you can get data from, adding orbital period, and the type of stuff, but it is by far the best tool I have ever found.

You seem to have a different issue with the tool and that is, "Why is x output detail pertinent?" Those can be seperate questions and you should ask those directly. But a biref overview:

Diameter: This tells you how big or small the planet is which tells you how much surface area in total you have to work with. It also tells you how much light a planet will block when it passes in front of a star.

Density: This tells you the general chemical make up of the world is. A heavier planet needs to have a higher abundance of heavier elements such as gold, platinum, and uranium.

Surface Area: Same as Diameter really, but a calculated out amount.

Roche Limit: This tells you how close a celestial body can get without it being torn apart. If you have a moon it has to be outside this limit or it is being torn apart. I think rings are within this limit but I'm not sure.

Surface Gravity: tell you what that average gravity is at sea level

To Orbit Velocity: Tell you how fast a thing must be going to maintain orbit., ie. not fall out of the sky.

Thrust to orbit time at 3G: This tells you have fast you will reach orbital velocity starting from the ground while accellerating at 3G. It's similar to the 0 to 60 measure.

Escape Velocity: The velocity that something needs to be travel to get out of its gravity well.

Comment: The transhuman.talktalk.net link is broken - can someone provide a current one? I would be very interested in the calculator.