# Super dense planet?

Tags: planets, gravity, rogue-planets

What's the most dense a planet could be and still be livable? How does water factor into the overall density of the planet. Is something like an osmium or iridium core even be possible/realistic?

If you had a planet 1/4th the size of earth but wanted the same or similar gravity, would that be possible or livable? Not talking probable, just possible.

How different would a gravity of 6, 7, or 8 be compared to 9.81 like earth?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. One question per post, please, with enough info to answer it. You can find more in the [help] and taking the [tour].

Comment: When you say 1/4 the "size" of earth, what do you mean? (mass or radius?)

Comment: Wow, this question sounds familiar.  This topic has had some discussion.
 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/47415/smallest-possible-habitable-planet-also-taking-density-into-account   https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71329/looking-for-a-planetary-calculator-for-the-mass-density-and-or-radius-of-a-pla  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100112/would-residents-of-a-small-planet-realize-the-planet-is-small

Comment: See also: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/76107/whats-the-smallest-reasonable-natural-planet-or-moon-with-earth-like-surface-gr https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96984/whats-the-biggest-reasonable-natural-planet-or-moon-with-earth-like-surface-gra

Comment: I suspect this will be closed -- consider that you didn't even specify "human-livable" vs  any type of life at all.   I recommend reading "Dragon's Egg"  for one extreme example.   Before you start creating your smaller world, you'll need to learn the relationship between radius and volume as well as  density issues.

Comment: Question, what life do you want to sustain? Depending on the life form, different things are necessary for life. What keeps humans alive, may be dangerous in oxygen levels, or water levels (etc) for another organism. My suggestion is to tell us what you want living on your planet. Going more in-depth on questions will help the community answer your questions to the best of our ability.